# android sms content uri in MI UI

Tags: android, sms, redmi-device

Is there any specific (or different) content URI that needs to be specified while reading SMS from Redmi Note 4 (MI UI 8.2.4).

The program was reading all SMS notification from Banks and other providers with sender ids while it was installed in Lenovo P1. But now the same App fails to read messages from MI UI 8.2.

I tried changing the content url from "content://sms/inbox" to "content://sms" but that just adds a few SENT messages and none from the SMSes of banks or any other providers who have "Sender Names" in the sender field.
Have anyone experienced this issue before?

Edit 1: Ok, I just understood that MI UI (Redmi Note 4) has another finer permission level for SMS named as Settings --> App Permissions --> Permissions Tab --> SMS & MMS --> Service SMS (read service SMS).

Comment: Is there a list of these extra permissions anywhere? I have the same issue with an S8+